# How do I collect redstone on iOS?

Tags: ios, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have found redstone and have tried using stone, iron and diamond pickaxes to mine it but I can't collect anything. I'm playing survival mode on my iPhone.

How can I collect anything from this redstone?

Answer (score 12):

The iOS version of Minecraft currently doesn't have Redstone items programmed into the game (if you go into Creative you won't find them), so breaking the ore will simply result in nothing dropping. You won't be able to collect any Redstone Dust until the game is updated to include the item.

Answer (score 5):

Mojang [announced a new version of Minecraft PE today](http://www.mojang.com/2012/08/minecraft-pocket-edition-0-4-0-submitted/). When this version is approved, Redstone will be added to creative mode, although they haven't mentioned if it will be functional as it is in the desktop Minecraft.

There is no Redstone in survival on PE, and no word on when it will be added, sorry.

Comment: POST MADE BY AN ANONYMOUS PERSON IN THE EDIT: "There are Redstone ore in survival mode on PE, but it can't be mine into dust, but only will destroy if you mine it."

Answer (score 0):

Is the block breaking on the first hit with the pick? If so, you're probably in [Creative mode](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Creative_%28Game_Mode%29). You can also check this if your inventory screen looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I am playing on my iphone in survival mode.

Comment: I would specify that in your question to get better answers.